# Is there a way to pass custom data through FBSDKAppInviteContent when using Facebook's Mobile Hosting API?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, fbsdk, fbsdkappinvitecontent

I'm trying to send data through an iOS Facebook app invite with Swift, which will then be attached to invite when the user responds.  My understanding is that this is similar to deep linking, however, I'm not sure whether I can send custom data when using Facebook's Mobile Hosting API as opposed to my own link.  Right now I'm using the `promotionCode` and `promotionText` attributes of `FBSDKAppInviteContent` to pass data through the invite, however, these attributes are shown to the user in the invite and I prefer to keep them hidden.  Is there any way to pass data through the invite that is not shown to the receiving user when using the Mobile Hosting API?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible with a plain vanilla App Invites implementation.

However, you can embed a [Branch](https://branch.io) link (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) to pass unlimited custom data through the App Invite process. Check out the integration process [here](https://dev.branch.io/marketing-channels/facebook-app-invites/).

Comment: Thanks, a friend mentioned this to me today.  I'll try it out.

Comment: Happy to answer any questions — just shout!